# How do computers, and computer-like devices such as phones, keep track of time?

Tags: desktop-computer, time, clock

I always wonder how timekeeping works on any electronic device; the basis on which it increments time units, such as every second or micro second.

Somewhere I read it works with a battery; but how?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same system as a regular [quartz clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_clock) (and/or [crystal oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator)). You have a quartz that oscillates. The battery is used to have a minimal system functional to keep time and keep a minimal amount of memory (CMOS) active in order to save that time and certain system configurations.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Crystal Oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator).

When a small amount of power is applied to a quartz crystal then that crystal begins to oscillate.  It outputs a very small signal that can be measured. The frequency of the oscillation is dependant on the size and shape of the crystal and quite consistent.

This oscillation can be used as the "tick" that drives a circuit that counts time. Because we know the frequency of the oscillator we know how many "ticks" there should be in a second a simple counter can be used to tell the actual timing circuit when specific amounts of time have passed.

A battery isn't the source of the time signals, it is used to keep the crystal and time circuits operational while the computer is switched off.  Because it is such a simple circuit it uses an incredibly small amount of current and a CR2032 battery can keep it running for years.

Typically though the crystal is used mainly during the periods the system is asleep and as a "base" clock from which other system clocks are derived. There are more accurate timekeeping methods that work at higher frequencies such as [Phase-locked loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) (PLLs) that can act as [clock multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_multiplier) which can take a low frequency clock and multiply it up to higher frequencies used by CPUs and other more finely grained timing devices.

Comment: Is the same method also used by CPUs? Most operating systems only read the battery-powered clock on boot, and rely solely on CPU timers until shutdown.

Comment: @grawity added a bit more detail

Comment: Are the CR2032's recharged whenever the computer is turned on?

Comment: No. While you can get rechargeable versions the CR2032 batteries used in computers are not rechargeable.

Comment: Decades ago, I had an IBM-branded laptop made by Fujitsu that did use a rechargeable CMOS battery. After about a year of usage, the battery would discharge if the laptop wasn't used for a month. I regularly had to reset things, and the battery was soldered in. They stopped making that laptop, and I haven't seen that mistake repeated since then.